# Apply class or function when a function is applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've create a [jQuery plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Image-Overlay-Hover-Effects-picturehover.html), that makes an overlay on hover effect over some images.

It works correctly, but then I thought about making the other images get an overlay as well when one is having the function of said plugin active. I thought about making this with `if`/`else` statements. like this:

```
jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3, #usp4').picturehover({
  fontColor:'#fff',
  textAlign:'center',
  verticalMiddle: true,
  backgroundColor:'rgba(79,47,82,0.85)',
  height:'100%',
});

    if(jQuery('#usp1').hasClass('hover-container'))
    {
        jQuery('#usp2, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
    }
    else if(jQuery('#usp2').hasClass('hover-container'))
    {
        jQuery('#usp1, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
    }
    else if(jQuery('#usp3').hasClass('hover-container'))
    {
        jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
    }
    else if(jQuery('#usp4').hasClass('hover-container'))
    {
        jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    };
```

The plugin gives the class hover-container to the image who has the effect. But the if else code does nothing. It gives no error, but won't fire. What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: Does not look like your if else statements are in an event listener

Comment: It would also be better to use common classes on the elements to DRY this logic up.

Answer (score 0):

Although I HIGHLY recommend utilizing a single class, the below code should trigger your if statement on slideIn and slideOUT

```
 jQuery.add_overlay = function(){
    if(jQuery('#usp1').hasClass('hover-container'))
        {
            jQuery('#usp2, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
        }
        else if(jQuery('#usp2').hasClass('hover-container'))
        {
            jQuery('#usp1, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
        }
        else if(jQuery('#usp3').hasClass('hover-container'))
        {
            jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
        }
        else if(jQuery('#usp4').hasClass('hover-container'))
        {
            jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)');
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3, #usp4').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
        };
    }

    jQuery('#usp1, #usp2, #usp3, #usp4').picturehover().on('slideInEnd slideOutEnd',function(event,data){
          jQuery.add_overlay();
        });
```

Comment: With a single class you mean that I replace the 4 id's with a single class? I understand that logic, it would make the code much shorter, am I right?